# Adding external library project

Tags: java, maven, android-studio

I'm using android studio and i want to add an external library project to my main project from [GitHub.com](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apmem.tools). I have created a folder named *libs* and add the whole module to it.Then like what is told in *github* i added this line of code to ***build.gradle*** file

```
compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
```

But i could not build my project and received this error

> Error:(9, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
>   Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

After searching about this problem find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/713099) and follow steps which has described there.

But now i receive this error

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>    Cannot evaluate module android-flowlayout-master : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

**EDIT :** my ***build.gradle*** file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you post what your `build.gradle` looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `build.gradle` files in Android projects. There is the project level one that's in the root of your project, and then there are the module level ones, which are in the subfolders of the modules. By default, you have one module in the project, called `app`.

When you're adding dependencies, you have to add them to the module's `build.gradle` file (which has the `android` block on top by default), inside the `dependencies` block. This is what the comment in the project level `build.gradle` is warning you about.

By default, this file is in the `app` folder. It looks like this if you're using the Android view of the project in Android Studio:

[image]